# How to check a date range in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to query the database to check if a date is within a range of two dates. There is a start date and end date. Essentially, I would like to display the values using the `BETWEEN` keyword.

I would like the date formats to match as well. Say `@date1` is `20150520`

```
DECLARE @startdate DATE
DECLARE @enddate DATE
DECLARE @date1 DATE
DECLARE @finaldate VARCHAR(1)

SET @startdate = DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE())
SET @enddate = GETDATE()
SET @date1 = '20150520'



SELECT record FROM table1
WHERE @date1 < @enddate AND @date1 > @startdate
```

This seems to make sense. Though when I try to use IF conditional I get NULL using the code below:

```
IF @date1 > @startdate AND @date1 < @enddate
BEGIN
SET @finaldate = '1'
END
ELSE IF @date1 > @enddate
BEGIN
SET @finaldate = '2'
END

SELECT @finaldate AS Final_Date
```

Though for some reason, `@finaldate` equates to NULL...which is not what I  would expect from the conditional branch.

Comment: can you please include how you are setting @date1 in your code block? I suspect it may be playing a role. Thanks!

Comment: I have added the `@date1` by using `SET @date1 = '20150520'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an additional branch on that conditional, if you're to cover all your bases:

```
ELSE IF @date1 <= @startdate
```

You've only tested for 1) between two dates and 2) greater than the last date.  At least one of those should include an equality check, as well, or else if your date is equal you won't match up.

Now, you *could* go with a plain old ELSE block at the end, to catch everything, but I suspect that you're actually looking for something more like:

```
IF @date1 > @startdate AND @date1 < @enddate
    BEGIN
        SET @finaldate = '1'
    END
ELSE IF @date1 >= @enddate
    BEGIN
        SET @finaldate = '2'
    END
ELSE IF @date1 <= @startdate
    BEGIN
        SET @finaldate = '3'
    END

SELECT @finaldate AS Final_Date
```